# Single word for a person who want to learn new things

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a person who always want to learn new things (new skills/informations)

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a noun? If an adjective is O.K., then probably *curious*.

Comment: You could very well use an adjective to describe such person. Such as, he is a curious person, or inquisitive for a better word

Comment: Inquisitive? To ask is to learn, to inquire is to ask.